# Up-to-date substrate template

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template

Since code was migrated to polkadot-sdk monorepo, what is the recommended way to obtain up-to-date parachain or standalone substrate template? I am interested in something that is migrated to v1.5.0

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Though not merged, you can use this if you want `polkadot-v1.5.0` exclusively : https://github.com/paritytech/extended-parachain-template/pull/100

Answer (score 1):

you can find them in [`polkadot-sdk/substrate/bin/node-template`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/release-polkadot-v1.5.0/substrate/bin/node-template) and [`polkadot-sdk/cumulus/parachain-template`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/release-polkadot-v1.5.0/cumulus/parachain-template), respectively. They are part of the `sdk`, so dependencies are in sync with it. The only problem you could face is dependencies pointing to local paths, instead of remote `polkadot-sdk` git repo. But I think you can use some script to auto-replace them or use a tool like [`diener`](https://github.com/paritytech/diener).